# How do we extract parts of a string in Perl?

Tags: regex, string, perl

I am new in `Perl`. I have a string of this format:
`[ timestamp  | integer | string  ] Some other string here`

Sample string:

```
[ 2013/05/28 21:39:02 | 2212 | MALFUNCTION  ] Please check for malfunction
```

The `timestamp` is actually a timestamp e.g. `2013/05/28 20:38:02`
The integer is a number and the string can be a specific word out of a sequence of words.
I am interested in extracting the string part of this.

In `Java` I would do it as simple as:

```
String s = sentence.substring(line.lastIndexOf("|") + 1, line.lastIndexOf("]")).trim();
```

This just loops over the string character by character and gets the part of interest.
But I don't how how this kind of "problems" are solved in `Perl`.
How would I do this? Only via regular expressions?

Comment: The question title is very unclear as to what you are asking, could you improve it?

Comment: @melwil:Is this better?

Comment: can you post a sample string?

Comment: re. your several basic questions about regular expressions: look through `perldoc perlretut`

Answer (score 11):

It does not have to be regex, but in Perl it is so damn convenient:

```
my $str = "[ timestamp | integer | string ] Some other string here";
my ($timestamp, $integer, $string, $other)
   = ($str =~ /\[(.*?)\|(.*?)\|(.*?)\](.*)/);
```

Comment: Ok figured it.The last `/` is missing in the answer snippet.But the `$other` is empty.

Answer (score 7):

You could do it just like Java:

- `String.substring` is [`substr`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/substr.html).
- `String.lastIndexOf` is [`rindex`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/rindex.html).
- `String.trim` is `sub trim { my $s = $_[0]; $s =~ s/^\s+//; $s =~ s/\s+\z//; $s }`.
- `+` is `.`.

But that method finds the last `|` and `]`, not the second and next respectively. It'll fail if either of those chars occur later in the string. I'd use

```
my ($ts, $i, $s, $rest) =
   map trim($_),
      /^\[ ([^|]*) \| ([^|]*) \| ([^\]]*) \] (.*)/sx;
```

Comment: In `/^\[ ([^|]*) \| ([^|]*) \| ([^\]]*) \] .*/sx;` I assume that the first `/` and the `/` before `sx` are equivalent to parenthesis? And what is `sx`? How does this work?

Comment: No, they're not. They're the match operator. `s` makes `.` match any char. `x` allows you use to use whitespace in the pattern for readability.

Comment: But `.` matches any char (except new line in regex) anyway. I don't understand this syntax.

Comment: If that's a question, maybe the answer is [perlretut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html)?

Answer (score 3):

If the strings you are matching don't contain other vertical bars, you could use a regular expression:

```
$fullstring = '[ timestamp | integer | string ] Some other string here';
($string) = ($fullstring =~ /\| *([^|\]]*?) *]/);
```

Comment: How does this work? I thought this syntax would only verify that the regex is contained in the string (`=~` is matches and `/` is instead of parenthesis right?).It extracts also?

Comment: @Cratylus: It will return the capture groups when in list context.

Answer (score 2):

Regular expressions are a natural Perl-ish way of doing things. In this case, we want the string between the last '|' and the first ']', minus any whitespace surrounding it.

```
my $string = ($line =~ m/
    \|  #The | character
    \s* #Arbitrary whitespace
    (   #Capture
        [^\|\]]*? #Some number of characters that are not | or ]
    )
    \s* #More whitespace
    \]  # The ] character
    /x)[0];
```

The idiom `(m/(reg)ex/)[0]` is used to extract the first capture group from the regular expression. Otherwise, an array of capture groups is returned and converted to a scalar (the length of the array).

The `/x` modifier on the regular expression causes whitespace and #comments to be ignored.

The `*?` token within the regular expression means "non-greedy" matching. Otherwise, the trailing whitespace would be captured, too.

Comment: What happens with the indexing of the array of capture groups i.e. `[0]` if the pattern is not contained in the exception?

Comment: @Cratylus In that case, then the array of matches is empty. The value of a non-existent index into an array is `undef`, so `$string` is `undef`.

Answer (score 1):

Line can be parsed by splitting on `|[]` chars, and then trimming spaces for extracted values

```
my @arr = map { s/^\s+ | \s+$//xg; $_ }  split / [\Q[]|\E] /x, $line;
```

after that `$arr[0]` is `timestamp` `$arr[1]` is `integer`, and so on.